# Unexpected value 'ModalModule' imported by the module 'DynamicTestModule'

Tags: angular, jestjs, ngx-bootstrap

I'm trying to test `MyComponent` which uses ngx-bootstrap's modal directive (as seen on https://valor-software.com/ngx-bootstrap/#/modals#directive-section ).
The component itself works flawlessly, but when trying to test it, I'm getting this error:

```
Unhandled Promise rejection: Unexpected value 'ModalModule' imported by the module 'DynamicTestModule'. Please add an @NgModule annotation.
```

This is what my TestBed looks like:

```
TestBed.configureTestingModule({
  imports: [
    HttpClientTestingModule,
    RouterTestingModule.withRoutes([]),
    ModalModule.forRoot()
  ],
  declarations: [MyComponent],
  providers: [],
  schemas: [ NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA ]
}).compileComponents().then(() => {
  fixture = TestBed.createComponent(MyComponent);
  component = fixture.componentInstance;
});
```

And this is how the modal is set on `MyComponent`:

```
export class MyComponent implements {
  @ViewChild('confirmDeleteModal')
  confirmDeleteView: ModalDirective;

  constructor() {} // empty constructor just to illustrate the fact that there are no other dependencies
```

For reference, here's the relevant part of my template:

```
<div bsModal #confirmDeleteModal="bs-modal" class="modal fade" role="dialog"> ... </div>
```

Here's what I've already tried:

Removing `ModalModule.forRoot()` from the list of `imports`, which then gives me this error:

```
Unhandled Promise rejection: Export of name 'bs-modal' not found!
```

Adding `ModalDirective` to the list of `declarations`:

```
Unhandled Promise rejection: R3InjectorError(DynamicTestModule)[ComponentLoaderFactory -> ComponentLoaderFactory]: 
  NullInjectorError: No provider for ComponentLoaderFactory!
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I believe this is usually a cache problem, try to restart the server and if that fails, try to restart both the ide and the server

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, but this is being run as a test, so there's nothing to restart.

Comment: Sorry i meant re-running the test`

Comment: Tried that, didn't work either. Also tried clearing all caches and nuking `node_modules` just in case to no avail.

Comment: Might the issue be in your actual code and not on the test? confirm that in your code you have imported `ModalModule.forRoot()` and not `ModalModule`

Comment: Yes, `ModalModule.forRoot()` is imported in `AppModule`

Comment: Is `MyComponent` declared in `AppModule` or in another module ?

Comment: `MyComponent` is declared in `ChildModule`, which is lazy loaded

Comment: And have you imported `ModalModule.forRoot()` or `ModalModule` in `ChildModule` ?

Comment: `ChildModule` imports `ModalModule` (without `forRoot()`)

Comment: There is your problem... Try to use `ModalModule.forRoot()`

Comment: From what I understand, `.forRoot()` is only supposed to be used on `AppModule`, any other module should not use it to avoid duplicate instances... In any case I tried it and got the same error.

Comment: See this issue on github https://github.com/valor-software/ngx-bootstrap/issues/2356

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/230260/discussion-between-guaycuru-and-owen-kelvin).

Answer (score 0):

You also need to add `BsModalService` to your providers array.

Comment: Unfortunately that didn't work either, this error still shows up: `Unhandled Promise rejection: Unexpected value 'ModalModule' imported by the module 'DynamicTestModule'. Please add an @NgModule annotation.`